# Making a CakePHP 1.2 page work on localhost

Tags: php, apache, cakephp

So I need to copy a site from a webserver and run it from my localhost.
The site is created with CakePHP 1.2.3.8166 (it says in VERSION.txt).

I am new to CakePHP, so i started with the 2.0 tutorial and i have also a fresh install of 1.2.11 and both work perfectly. (I just had to fix the mod_rewrite issues by enabling AllowOverride All).

However when i tried to run my downloaded site i just got "page not found" error.
With a little searching, the solution was to remove the first "/" in 
"RewriteRule    ^$ /app/webroot/    [L]" and other places in the .htaccess files.

So now my page looks wired, like this:
http://pastebin.com/ZMX3RjZG

Clearly the page does't load properly and i don't know what is wrong.
Now i am stuck, anyone have come across similar problem?

I run:
Windows 7 Pro 64bit,
PHP 5.3.6,
Apache 2.2.19

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why do you use a tutorial for CakePHP 2.0 with CakePHP 1.2.11?

Comment: No. I have both CakePHP 2.0 and 1.2.11 installed. I just did the 2.0 tutorial, just for learning.

Comment: That looks weird indeed, almost as if the PHP isn't parsed correctly. Does a regular PHP script render correctly? Also, could you provide the code for that view, not the rendered result?

Comment: Well, I run other sites (drupal, cakephp2.0) from my localhost and php works correctly on them, and this site runs perfectly on the webserver it was taken from. which view code do you mean?

Comment: PHP should be running then. I mean the code of the view of that particular page. Part of it is probably in `default.ctp` in `/views/layouts/` the rest is in ctp file in the corresponding directory in `/view/`.

Comment: Ok, here it is. http://pastebin.com/A6GWrjxF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the second code sample you've provided and the way the rendered content is garbled I would say that shorthand tags aren't enabled in your version of PHP.

This shorthand notation might be the root of your problem:

```
<?= //Some PHP script ?>
```

There are two solutions, either change all the shorthand tags to the full declaration:

```
<?php //Some PHP script ?>
```

Which might be quite an undertaking as you're working with an existing project. It all depends on the size of it and if this shorthand notation is present in all of the files (the Cake core uses the full declaration). Or you could enable shorthand in your `php.ini` and restart the Apache server.

More information on shorthand tags can be found in [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php).